# SQL Server 'Invalid column' on a SELECT query to a temp table - CASE SENSITIVITY issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a case where I have **NO** control whatsoever on the SQL Server configuration.

Here's my configuration:

- SQL Server 2008
- SQL Server INSTANCE Collation: Latin_General_BIN (Which I know is case-sensitive)
- A given database (Which is not case-sensitive... SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)

**Here's the scenario I want... if possible:**

***Given***

```
CREATE DATABASE given_database;

USE given_database;

CREATE TABLE #test (Field1 nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS);
```

***When***

```
SELECT field1 FROM #test; /*Notice the lower case on field1*/
```

***Then***

> Invalid column name 'field1'

Is there a way to make this work?

I know this is something that no one would want to have but since I am stuck with this configuration on my client side and we have a lot of legacy code that have different casing in the queries... I wanted to know if there's a work around.

Comment: Yet another reason for stored procs instead of queries in code. This would defeat the unique names in a case sensitive collation. You can have field1, Field1 and FIELD1 in the same table in a case sensitive collation. And they can even be the same or different datatypes. In other words, what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Your only option with a SQL Server that was installed with a case sensitive collation is to ensure that all references to temp tables are properly cased. If you have no option to re-install the SQL Server instance with a different case-insensitive collation, or install a new case-insensitive instance, then you have no option but to ensure all your SQL references tables & columns with the proper case. Sorry. It's a good habit to be in regardless.

Comment: No, if there is any chance, then move your database to a server instance with the same collation as your database. Different collations are always a pain in the neck...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make this work?

Not with a temp table, no.
Tempdb inherits the instance default collation. You've defined the column with a case insensitive collation which should let you ask for value comparisons in a case insensitive manner, but the column name itself falls into the database collation so it needs to be referred to as defined.

```
CREATE TABLE #test (Field1 nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS);

INSERT INTO #test 
VALUES ('test'),('TEST'),('Test')

SELECT field1 FROM #test --should fail
SELECT Field1 FROM #test WHERE Field1 = 'tEst' --should work
```